# My simple HTTPS Java server throws exception: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Tags: java

I've implemented a HTTPS server which sends a simple index.html file to a browser. I've used Eclipse as my IDE, and I have a `.jks` file as well along with the program. Interestingly, **when I run the program on Eclipse, everything is fine**. On the browser I request `https://localhost:8888` (my defined port), it warns about my certificate, I confirm, and it retrieves the page. But when I run the program via terminal (`java HTTPSserver`), the server shows the following exception. I searched for it and noticed similar posts, but **was not able to find a concrete set of steps to solve the problem.** Can someone help me with this?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1705)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:972)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ServerHandshaker.java:1532)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientFinished(ServerHandshaker.java:1492)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:243)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
....[more lines]
```

here is the part of the server code responsible for key stuff:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ksName = "mykey.jks";
    char ksPass[] = "mypass".toCharArray();
    char ctPass[] = "mypass".toCharArray();
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8888,0, null);
    ...[more lines]
}
```

Comment: Don't hardcore the keymanagerfactory string.  It has a different name on IBM JVM's

Comment: It shouldn't be the cause of the error, right?